# How to show a random variable diverges from its mean?

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following statement which seem not to be very complicated but I cannot find a straightforward way to prove it (can it even be wrong?):

Suppose $X_n$ are a sequence of random variables with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma^2_n$. We know (by Chebyshev's inequality) that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sigma^2_n}{\mu_n^2} = 0$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left[X_n \in [(1-\epsilon) \mu_n, (1+\epsilon) \mu_n] \right] = 1.
\end{equation*}

Now, I want to prove the following statement: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sigma_n^2}{\mu_n^2} = \infty$ then 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left[X_n \in [(1-\epsilon) \mu_n, (1+\epsilon) \mu_n] \right] = 0.
\end{equation*}

Does anyone have an idea how to show the above (or even if the above is correct)?

Comment: This is not called a converse, it is an altogether different statement.

Comment: @MBP : The _converse_ of the statement "If A then B" is the statement "If B then A".  Taking the _converse_ means reversing the roles of "if" and "then".  The statement you're calling a converse is not a converse: it is not arrived at by interchanging "if" and "then".

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false.  Take

$$X_n = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{ with probability } 1-1/n,\\
                      n^{3/4}, & \text{ with probability } 1/n. \end{cases}$$

Then $\mu_n=n^{-1/4}$ and $\sigma_n^2=\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}$, but

$$\forall\epsilon>0: \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr(|X_n-\mu_n|\leq \epsilon) =1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jpi. However, I guess my statement is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr[ |X_n - \mu_n| < \epsilon \mu_n]$ (there is scaling factor of $\mu_n$ difference there). 

In your example this will translate to $\Pr[ |Y_n - 1| < \epsilon ]$ where $Y_n \in \{0,n\}$ and $\Pr[Y_n = 0] = 1 - 1/n$ (indeed $Y_n = n^{1/4} X_n$). Unless $\epsilon = 1$ the probability of $\{|Y_n - 1| \le \epsilon\}$ is $0$.

Comment: @ClementC.Are you sure? $X_n = 0$ implies $|X_n - \mu_n| = \mu_n \not\le \epsilon \mu_n$ if $\epsilon < 1$.

Comment: @MBP: you are right, sorry.

Comment: True, then replacing the value of zero with one should work, no?  So $X_n=1$ wp $1-1/n$ and $X_n=n^{3/4}$ wp $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to JPi's, here's another attempt at a counter example, with the multiplicative concentration. Define $X_n$ to be the random variable supported on $\{-n,\frac{1}{1-1/n},n\}$ by
$$
X_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \begin{cases}
n &\text{ w.p. } \frac{1}{2n} \\
\frac{1}{1-1/n} &\text{ w.p. } 1-\frac{1}{n} \\
-n &\text{ w.p. } \frac{1}{2n}
\end{cases}
$$
You have $\mu_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\mathbb{E}X_n = 1$, and the variance is defined and equal to 
$$
\sigma^2_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\operatorname{Var}X_n = \mathbb{E}[X^2_n] - 1 = n + \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}} - 1 = n+o(1)
$$
so that indeed $\frac{\sigma^2_n}{\mu^2_n} = n+o(1) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$. But on the other hand, fixing any $\epsilon > 0$, you have that for any $n\geq 1/\epsilon+1$
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X_n - \mu_n\rvert \leq \epsilon \mu_n \} = \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X_n - 1\rvert \leq \epsilon \} = \mathbb{P}\left\{X_n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n} }\right\} = 1-\frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1.
$$

Comment: Nice. So it seems the statement is false. I just wonder if we limited the random variables to be positive, i.e. $X_n \ge 0$ could we find a counter example?

Comment: Yes, see my comment on my own answer.

Comment: Sure. Not the simplest, maybe, but consider 
$$
X_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \begin{cases}
n^2 &\text{ w.p. } \frac{1}{n^3} \\
\frac{1-1/n}{1-1/n^3} &\text{ w.p. } 1-\frac{1}{n^3}
\end{cases}
$$
You still have $\mu_n=1$, $\sigma_n^2 = n + o(n)$, and 
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X_n - \mu_n\rvert \leq \epsilon \mu_n \} = 1-\frac{1}{n^3} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1.
$$